# How to create a view that returns all child records in a single row without aggregation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

I am an electrical engineer developing a parts library database and explorer tool for internal use in my organization. If anyone is familiar with OrCAD schematic capture tools, I am essentially recreating Cadence's CIS (Component Information System) backend and CIP (Component Information Portal) frontend , but I attempting to make them CAD software agnostic (should work with OrCAD, Altium, KiCAD, etc). I am nearly at the finish line, but am getting tripped up with the database views I need to feed data into my CAD software

At the moment I have 6 tables that all contain different types of data about each part:

| Table Name | Purpose | Relationships |
| --- | --- | --- |
| classes | Part categories | Parent to Main |
| main | Descriptive identifying information and data for CAD tools | Child of classes, Many-to-One. Parent to all other tables. Has Internal Part Number (IPN) used as foreign key in the other tables. |
| performance_spec | Part ratings used for automated part stress derating analysis. Part class determines criteria. | Child of main, One-to-One |
| manufacturing | Manufactures and Part Numbers | Child of main, Many-to-One |
| procurement | Suppliers and Part Numbers | Child of main, Many-to-One |
| compatibility | Cross reference alternative parts - Same Form, Fit, and Function with small differences in finish, reliability rating, etc. | Child of main, Many-to-One |

The main issue is that the CAD software, which communicates with the database via ODBC, cannot handle data split into multiple tables. So I need to create views (one per library -- grouped by class) that display queries of joined data from each of the tables.

The "Many-to-One" relationships between records is posing a particular problem because I need to represent all child records in the manufacturing table in a single row with the parent records in the main table.

I currently have a view that pulls in all of the child records using LEFT JOINs, but each child record in the manufacturing table creates a new row. I need some way to query the data so all of the child records are in a single row.

Here are simplified structures of the main and manufacturing tables along with some sample data.

**main**

| id | ipn | part_class | part_value | description | package | spec_doc | sch_symbol_kicad | pwb_fotprint_kicad | last_modified_user | last_modified_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRT-00000001 | RES, Other | 10k | RES, SMT, Thick Film, 10k, 1%, 100ppm, 0.15 W | 0805 |  | res | resc0805 | FLast | 2023-05-04 07:38:53.782386-04 |
| 2 | PRT-00000002 | CAP, Tantalum, Solid | 15u | CAP, SMT, Tantalum, 220u, 10%, 10V, Reliability Grade D, Surge Test Option C | 2214 | MIL-PRF-55365/11 | cap_p | capc2214 | FLast | 2023-05-03 07:31:05.815801-04 |

**manufacturing**

| id | ipn | mfr | mpn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRT-00000001 | Yageo | RC0805JR-0710KL |
| 2 | PRT-00000001 | Stackpole Electronics Inc | RNCP0805FTD10K0 |
| 3 | PRT-00000001 | Susumu | RG2012P-103-B-T5 |
| 4 | PRT-00000002 | Kemet | T429F156K020DC4252 |
| 5 | PRT-00000002 | Kyocera AVX | CWR29JC156KDFC |

I'd like to create a view that looks like this:

| ipn | part_class | part_value | description | package | spec_doc | sch_symbol_kicad | pwb_fotprint_kicad | mfr_1 | mpn_1 | mfr_2 | mpn_2 | ... | mfr_n | mpn_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

If someone could help me figure out a query to structure the manufacturing table with all records corresponding to the same IPN in a single row that would be a huge help. Joining that with the main table or any others should be straight-forward.

Thanks in advance!

Here's some SQL code to recreate tables:

```
CREATE TABLE components.main (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ipn components.citext DEFAULT to_char(nextval('components.main_ipn_seq'::regclass), '"PRT-"fm00000000'::text) NOT NULL,
    part_class integer NOT NULL,
    part_value components.citext NOT NULL,
    description components.citext NOT NULL,
    spec_doc components.citext,
    sch_symbol_kicad components.citext,
    sch_symbol_altium components.citext,
    pwb_footprint_kicad components.citext,
    pwb_footprint_altium components.citext,
    step_file components.citext,
    lead_frm_reqd boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    lead_finish components.citext,
    datasheet components.citext,
    last_modified_user components.citext DEFAULT USER NOT NULL,
    last_modified_timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    nrnd boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    bom_exclusion integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    pwb_exclusion integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    package components.citext
);

ALTER TABLE components.main ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME components.main_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);

CREATE SEQUENCE components.main_ipn_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE components.manufacturing (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ipn components.citext NOT NULL,
    mfr components.citext NOT NULL,
    mpn components.citext NOT NULL,
    cage components.citext
);

ALTER TABLE components.manufacturing ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME components.manufacturing_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);
```

I have looked into pivoting and cross-tab functions, but every example I've seen has used aggregations on numerical data, which doesn't directly apply to me. Also, the examples seem to use a single column in the source table to define the columns of the pivot table as "categories." I am finding it difficult to adapt that concept to what I want to do where I want to treat each mfr and mpn pair as unique.

**Edit-002**
I figured out how to get the view to display what I wanted using nested/sub queries, but it's pretty slow (~100-200ms for ~200 records). Any recommendations for performance optimization strategies would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.manf_pair_index
AS
SELECT manufacturing.id,
    manufacturing.ipn,
    manufacturing.mfr,
    manufacturing.mpn,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY manufacturing.ipn ORDER BY manufacturing.id, manufacturing.ipn) AS pair_num
    FROM manufacturing;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.manf_flat
AS
SELECT manf_pair_index.ipn,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 1) AS mfr_1,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 1) AS mpn_1,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 2) AS mfr_2,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 2) AS mpn_2,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 3) AS mfr_3,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 3) AS mpn_3,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 4) AS mfr_4,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 4) AS mpn_4,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 5) AS mfr_5,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 5) AS mpn_5
    FROM manf_pair_index
    GROUP BY manf_pair_index.ipn;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.resistors
AS
SELECT main.ipn,
    main.nrnd,
    main.part_class,
    main.part_value,
    main.description,
    main.package,
    main.spec_doc,
    main.lead_finish,
    main.lead_frm_reqd,
    manf_flat.mfr_1,
    manf_flat.mpn_1,
    manf_flat.mfr_2,
    manf_flat.mpn_2,
    manf_flat.mfr_3,
    manf_flat.mpn_3,
    manf_flat.mfr_4,
    manf_flat.mpn_4,
    manf_flat.mfr_5,
    manf_flat.mpn_5,
    compatibility.comperable_ipn,
    main.sch_symbol_kicad,
    main.sch_symbol_altium,
    main.pwb_footprint_kicad,
    main.pwb_footprint_altium,
    main.step_file,
    main.bom_exclusion,
    main.pwb_exclusion
    FROM main
        LEFT JOIN manf_flat ON main.ipn::text = manf_flat.ipn::text
        LEFT JOIN compatibility ON main.ipn::text = compatibility.ipn::text
    WHERE main.part_class > 28 AND main.part_class < 45
    ORDER BY main.ipn;
```

Comment: Rather than model the objects into tables, have you considered storing the serialised object into a single column, say as json? You may consider using NoSQL too.

Comment: If the number of the columns is dynamic - i.e. it depends on the number of rows in the child table - then you can't do this in pure SQL because SQL requires fixed number of columns that are known before the query is executed. In this case you will have to combine the columns inside your application rather than in the database. Or, you will have to first determine the rows in the child table with one query and then dynamically build another query with the already known number of columns.

Comment: You mention using an heirarchical query, but don't present any. Please post the explain plan. It's impossible to offer more than general suggestions without additional details.

Comment: @JohnH - Apologies for the confusion. I misused the term. I suppose I am actually using nested/sub queries.

Comment: @Bohemian - I am not developing a web apps where I am merely concerned with displaying the data nicely to the user. The schematic capture software requires the data to be in a specific format in a table or view which is accessed directly via ODBC. I don't think JSON will help me with this.

Comment: @IVOGELOV - I am ok with limiting the view to 5 mfr-mpn pairs, which I have done in my nested query solution. Any tips for making this faster?

Comment: Please post the query's explain plan. Without the insights that reviewing the plan might provide, any suggestions we make are just shots in the dark. A small amount of sample data would also be helpful. It won't help isolate performance issues, but it will make it easier to craft correct queries.

Comment: There's quite a lot going on in this question. To make it easier to understand what you want and easier for us to code something up, please create a [mcve] at say https://www.db-fiddle.com or https://dbfiddle.uk that includes sample data and edit your question to include the link and the expected result.